# Apache tomcat works temporary - restart iptables for work

Tags: iptables, centos6, linux-networking, tomcat7

I have an apache tomcat installed on CentOS linux on a VPS. I have opened port 8080 in iptables so that it will be visit-able from outside. My problem is that when I go to address example.com:8080 it shows nothing and connection times out. But when I write the command `service iptables restart` in terminal it will work for a short while after it and again when I go to the address example.com:8080 the connection times out.
Thanks in advance.

**EDITED**
Current iptables configuration file in `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`

```
# Firewall configuration written by system-config-firewall   
# Manual customization of this file is not recommended   
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -i eth+ -p tcp --dport 25 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8025
COMMIT
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8044 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
```

**UPDATED**
Telnet response in not responding state.
    telnet ip.address 8080
*Response*

```
Connecting To that.ip.address...Could not open connection to the host, on port 8080:
 Connect failed
```

Comment: Can you confirm that you're running the listener (`netstat -in|grep 8080`) and tell us what your rules are (`iptables -L -n -v`)?

Comment: @MadHatter if it response while restarting `iptables`, that means port 8080 is listens, it's clearly firewall that prevents his access to tomcat.

Comment: I'd buy that, except that `iptables` rules don't rot and suddenly change what they permit **either**.  So his problem doesn't exist - *except that it does*.  It's always a good idea to check the basics in examples like this (actually, it's a pretty good rule *all* the time).

Comment: @MadHatter `netstat -in|grep 8080` has no output. But I'm sure that tomcat is running.

Comment: I'm very sorry, that was a typo on my part.  Try `netstat -an|grep 8080`.  I do apologise.  Can you also confirm that the VPS has a public IP address, or is there some other port-forwarding device in the loop?

Comment: @iman disable firewall temporary, just to rule it out all together `service iptables stop`, if port 8080 starts to responds it's firewall, if not then whatever runs on port 8080 is at fault.

Comment: @alexus When I disable firewall it works.

Comment: @MadHatter the output is tcp        0      0 :::8080                     :::*                        LISTEN

Comment: Just in case the state engine is treading on your feet, try changing `-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT` to `-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT`.  Also, you didn't answer about public IP addresses.

Comment: @MadHatter  Sorry i forgot,it has a public ip address.

Comment: @MadHatter It responded for about five minutes and stopped responding.

Comment: And that public IP address is the one you're contacting?  Could you cut-and-paste into your question the command and output of `telnet that.ip.address 8080` **when you're in the stopped-responding situation**?

Comment: @MadHatter Updated my question.

Comment: Thanks for posting the real IP, it helps.  I notice that I also can't connect to port 22, and that port 25 is *amazingly* slow to respond.  Is there any chance that you're simply overloading this VPS?  Do you just restart `iptables` to get it to respond (and if so how, given that you can't ssh in) or are you restarting **the entire VPS**?

Comment: @MadHatter It was a mistake :).  What do you mean by overriding VPS? I just restart iptables using ssh.

Comment: Over**loading**, not over**riding**.  And how, given that you can't `ssh` in?  Could we see your live ruleset (`iptables -L -n -v`), just to check it's taken?

Comment: Oh sorry. I can ssh in.

Answer (score 0):

try `man iptables` and be careful not to lock yourself out, also get yourself familiar with following:

[How To Setup a Basic IP Tables Configuration on Centos 6 | DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-a-basic-ip-tables-configuration-on-centos-6)

probably following is missing:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: :Thanks but it's already included in my iptables . see updated question.